# Why Does This Randomize String Batch Script Always Start With The First Letter From the Character List?

Tags: batch-file

Unfortunately I'm unable to add comments to an existing StackOverflow article as my rep isn't high enough, so I'll reference the link here:
[runonce-to-rename-a-computername-with-a-random-name-on-reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679369/runonce-to-rename-a-computername-with-a-random-name-on-reboot)

Why does the batch sample code that [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41349617/6811411) provided always prefix the randomly generated part with the first letter from the character list, e.g. "A"?

Sample code:

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Chars=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
Call :RandChar 26 Name
For /L %%A in (1,1,14) Do Call :RandChar 62 Name
Echo %Name%
Goto :Eof
:RandChar Range Var
Set /A Pnt=%Random% %% %1 & Set %2=!%2!!Chars:~%Pnt%,1!
```

Result when executed 10 times:

```
AOyVq8olMi7kZaR
ANyU2MoAzZwTpwo
AYNXqJSGKXgyvca
AFGoCImfNOHuVSz
AHNhxnj9Wyqkqo3
AML6hTrSHK4TFut
AHuinBZCWr5D5NZ
AQYNtXaYMXRdGOb
ARWYXn7YNMQ0cmm
APHdWggSQl5KUhA
```

How can the code be modified to randomise the starting character too?

Comment: Without testing anything, I'm going to preemptively blame delayed expansion, because that's usually the source of batch problems. Does using `!random!` instead of `%random%` work?

Comment: Unfortunately the result appears to be the same. I generated about 15-20 different values and they all still started with A

Comment: Put the `set %2` part of the last line on its own line. Something something variable expansion not kicking in when you use `&`.

Comment: Genius! That worked :D   Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Set /A Pnt=%Random% %% %1 & Set %2=!%2!!Chars:~%Pnt%,1!
```

should be

```
Set /A Pnt=%Random% %% %1
Set %2=!%2!!Chars:~%Pnt%,1!
```

The *entire* line is parsed, then executed and during the parsing phase, any `%var%` will be replaced by the value of var`at that time. Hence,`pnt`will be replaced by the value of`pnt`at the very start, yielding`Set %2=!%2!!Chars:~,1!` and thereafter it will be replaced by the value established on the *previous* call.

Breaking the line forces the two statements to be executed sequentially.